# How to get the path of an antivirus installed in my system from my C# program?

Tags: c#, .net

My C# program needs to open the antivirus installed in my machine.

As of now I have hardcoded the path as follows:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:/Program Files (x86)/MyAntivirus/myAntivirus.exe");
```

However the path varies for a 32 and 64 bit machine. I cannot run the same code on my 64 bit windows 8.1 machine.

Is there any way to get the path of the antivirus installed in my machine so that my program is machine independent?

Comment: You could always put the path into a **.NET config** file ....

Comment: how can you be sure it is installed on `C:` drive? You can be sure only if the AntiVirus installer writes the installdir somewhere, from example, in registry, in which case, you can write some code to query the registry.

Comment: You may have to dynamically create the path to the antivirus folder.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of hardcoding the path to the antivirus, you can ask windows where the path is. Most antivirus programs report themselves to windows. So that windows wont report to the users that no antivirus is installed.

Using WMI you can query windows for that path.

```
var searcherPreVista = new ManagementObjectSearcher(string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\SecurityCenter", Environment.MachineName), "SELECT * FROM AntivirusProduct");
var searcherPostVista = new ManagementObjectSearcher(string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\SecurityCenter2", Environment.MachineName), "SELECT * FROM AntivirusProduct");
var preVistaResult = searcherPreVista.Get().OfType<ManagementObject>();
var postVistaResult = searcherPostVista.Get().OfType<ManagementObject>();

var instances = preVistaResult.Concat(postVistaResult);

var installedAntivirusses = instances
    .Select(i => i.Properties.OfType<PropertyData>())
    .Where(pd => pd.Any(p => p.Name == "displayName") && pd.Any(p => p.Name == "pathToSignedProductExe"))
    .Select(pd => new
    {
        Name = pd.Single(p => p.Name == "displayName").Value,
        Path = pd.Single(p => p.Name == "pathToSignedProductExe").Value
    })
    .ToArray();

foreach (var antiVirus in installedAntivirusses)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", antiVirus.Name, antiVirus.Path);
}
```

To use this code, you need to add the following using statements:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;
```

Further more. Add a reference to `System.Management`.

This code will generate a list of all antivirusses installed. The objects in the list will have a name and path. If I run the code it shows the following:

> Microsoft Security Essentials: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client\msseces.exe

Comment: when i run the code, it shows:

Norton Internet Security: C:\Program Files (x86)\Norton Internet Security\Engine\20.1.0.24\WSCStub.exe

However,I need to open the antivirus,hence if I give the path:

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(antivirus.Path.ToString())

The norton gui does not open.

Comment: when i manually go to the path and try running the WSCStub.exe,the gui does not open. However, if u navigate to:C:\Program Files (x86)\Norton Internet Security\Engine64\20.1.0.24\uiStub.exe,the gui opens

Comment: The path you get from the query is the path to the antivirus program. The path to the UI might be different (as you have found out.) Because this path is different for every antivirus you can't get it in C#. Unless you create a list of all known AV + the path to the correct UI exe. Then filter that with the list you get from the query... But how to find every UI exe path of every AV?

Comment: yeah but that is my real need. I have to open the AV gui without hardcoding the path.Clueless!

Comment: Like I said, you can't. There is no single guide line which you can follow. Every AV does it different.

Comment: Suppose I manage to collect UI exe path of the AVs that I am using, then is it possible to dynamically get the whole UI path to start the UI from my project?

Comment: yes. Suppose you have a list of `{ Name = "", UIPath = ""}` this list is named 'avUIPaths'. Then you execute my code, you get the list called `installedAntivirusses`. Now you execute the following code:
`var filteredPaths = avUIPaths.Where(avUI => installedAntivirusses.Select(avP => avP.Name).Contains(avUI.Name));` By this you filter your list with myList based on the names. Then your list is reduced to a list of UI paths installed on the computer.

Comment: what u have suggested is that i store the whole path C:\Program Files (x86)\Norton Internet Security\Engine64\20.1.0.24\uiStub.exe in a list and then query using the av name? But what i meant was,suppose i just store the exe names in a list like uiStub.exe,then is it possible for me to get the whole path of the exe location?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to dynamically create the path to the AV folder.

```
string programFilesDirPath= Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86);
string path = Path.Combine(programFilesDirPath,"MyAntivirus","myAntivirus.exe");
```

Hope this helps!